# How to concatenate these strings if their corresponding windows dont exist?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to create a string for the FindText library. At any given time I could have 1-15 windows that I need to search for a specific graphic in. I want eliminate these windows as much as I can before moving on to the FindText section of my code.

The alternative is to pass a large string consisting of `Align`, `Project`, `Tools`, `Browser` and many more to FindText. I am trying to avoid this.

---

## Code:

```
AE_Exe  := "ahk_class DroverLord - Window Class ahk_exe AfterFX.exe"

Align       := "|<Align>*122$45.zrzzzzzzSrzzzzzlrzzzzU6iq27zzzpqqqTzzxqqqvzw0UqtrTzzxqqyvzzzTGsrTzU7zyvzzzzzzrTzzzzzy7zzzzU"
Project := "|<Project>*122$54.3zyzzjzzzRzzzzjzw0RX6ss7zzzRimqrjzzz3iukrjzw0TiurrjzzzTimrrjzzzTj6ssbzw0zzyzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzxzzzzzzU"
Tools       := "|<Tools>*122$46.zzzjzzzw3zyzzzzyzzvzzw0vllgTzzzimmrzzzyvffTzw0viiiTzzzimmxzzzywQN7zw0U"
Browser := "|<Browser>*122$60.3zzzzzzzzzRzzzzzzzw0RX4qllXzzz3imarhjzzzRiuerVjzw0RiuftjjzzzRinNxjjzzz3j7Nlljzw0U"

Panels  := !WinExist("AE_Window Align " AE_Exe)         ? Panels . Align
            :   !WinExist("AE_Window Project " AE_Exe)  ? Panels . Project
            :   !WinExist("AE_Window Tools " AE_Exe)    ? Panels . Tools
            :   !WinExist("AE_Window Browser " AE_Exe)  ? Panels . Browser
            :   ""
```

## Expected Outcome:

If for example only the following windows exist:

- `AE_Window Align ahk_class DroverLord - Window Class ahk_exe AfterFX.exe`
- `AE_Window Tools ahk_class DroverLord - Window Class ahk_exe AfterFX.exe`

The string in `Panels` should be:

```
"|<Align>*122$45.zrzzzzzzSrzzzzzlrzzzzU6iq27zzzpqqqTzzxqqqvzw0UqtrTzzxqqyvzzzTGsrTzU7zyvzzzzzzrTzzzzzy7zzzzU|<Tools>*122$46.zzzjzzzw3zyzzzzyzzvzzw0vllgTzzzimmrzzzyvffTzw0viiiTzzzimmxzzzywQN7zw0U"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!